# Cakephp Find Problem

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I have a deals table, with a field start date in the controller i am trying the below code and it is not returning any deal when there is deals with these conditions

Here's the codes:

```
function todays_deal($CitySlug = null) {

        $city = $this->City->find('first', array('conditions' => array('City.slug' => $CitySlug)));
        $CityID = $city['City']['id'];
        $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $conditions = array(
            'Deal.city_id' => $CityID,
            'Deal.type' => 'F',
            'Deal.start >=' => $now
        );

        $deal = $this->Deal->find('first',array('conditions'=> $conditions, 'order' => 'Deal.start DESC'));
    $left = array();
        $now = time();
        //Change dates to timestamp
        $end = strtotime($deal['Deal']['end']);
        $start = strtotime($deal['Deal']['start']);
        if($end < $start){
            $end = $start;
        }

        $diff_time = $left_time = $end - $now;

        if ($start >= $now ) {
            $diff_time = $left_time = $start - $now;
        }

        $left_day = floor($diff_time/86400);
        $left_time = $left_time % 86400;
        $left_hour = floor($left_time/3600);
        $left_time = $left_time % 3600;
        $left_minute = floor($left_time/60);
        $left_time = $left_time % 60;

        $this->set(compact('deal', 'left_day', 'left_hour', 'left_minute', 'left_time', 'now', 'diff_time'));

    }
```

I am totally lost to why this isnt returning any deals as it should.

All help appreciated

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you turn up the [debug level in CakePHP](http://www.devdaily.com/php/cakephp-debug-configure-debug-output), it should dump out the queries used.

Check the SQL generated for your select - perhaps the date format is the problem.

Comment: Thanks realised that it was checking the time for the start date lol :)